# Effects of Methamphetamine

Tags: drugs

When I walk downtown in Seattle, I often see individuals who appear to be "high" on various substances, "crouched" down(bent over) and rocking back and forth. I asked about this since I was curious and "locals" told me it's usually Methamphetamines (Meth) that makes them do this.

This behavior seems to be common among them when they are under the influence. I'm genuinely curious to understand the reasons behind this specific behavior. What could be causing drug addicts to exhibit rocking and crouching movements while high? Are there any psychological or physiological factors that contribute to this behavior?

I would be grateful if someone could explain this in plain English. My psychology lingo ends with Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs, unfortunately.

Please note that my intention is solely to seek knowledge and understand the underlying causes, without passing judgment.

Comment: Why you didn't ask narcos?

Comment: Welcome! The question seems acceptable to me. I removed the unnecessary preamble.

Comment: @άνθρωπος What? Last time I checked "*narcos*" usually aren't neuroscientists...

Comment: Not an answer, because the observed behaviour could have a number of antecedents. Without reproducing the Wikipedia page on the topic: [psycho-motor agitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychomotor_agitation) has many manifestations and many causes. Bear-in-mind that many of the street people may be suffering in other ways than drug thrall or withdrawal (see list at the bottom of the page). [Stimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimming) has some closer relation to your description, and is related to coping mechanisms for unpleasant anxiety states.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks, yeah now I noticed my question is very "broad" in a way. The reason why I am somewhat sure this is Methamphetamines is because of many news report articles and videos (*with experts*) that talk about meth abuse in Seattle. As I said I am not judging but just curious to know why that happens. To me the bent-over position and rocking does not seem comfortable at all, and I figured it's something else that makes them do this.

Comment: bent-over position and rocking - uncontrolled motions, tired, looks like Drug withdrawal, not like buzzing. looks like they feel bad, maybe they have broken their nervous already. So, i said that you should to ask, because you can ask them atleast what drug stage are they and what drug they eat. Your curiosity is too idle and too abstractive, without a cause.

Comment: It's also worth adding the effects of bad or lacking nutrition (or infections/toxins) in [abdominal guarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_guarding), that with other contributing factors can make a single diagnosis moot.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. yes, it can be a tired from hungering for a several days, because there are no hanger under some drugs effect and/or problems with a stomach, and unable to have meal, met- is one of these drugs too. And narco need to choose or food or current dose. So it can be not only "neuro" problem, but physical and social. But ofc the root is drug getting